# ADF how to trigger a clientListener from the bean?

Tags: javascript, events, listener, javabeans, oracle-adf

here is what I'm trying to do.

My ADF page is embedded inside a web page and I must set some values in the parent window.

To do so I have a javascript function that does the work just fine.
to get the value I need to push, I must call an external API with some parameter that depend on a user click.

I implement the call in my manage bean, I get the value and I push it in an input field on my page.

I also setup a clientListener(valueChange) on the inputfield to call my javascript function.

In theory it should do just fine.

**the issue is that after the user invoked my serverListener event that call the API, the clientListener is not invoked when the value is pushed inside the inputfield.**

I've let the field visible for testing and I can enter the value myself and it work but when the bean push the value in the field the valueChange event doesn't get trigger.

The question from there is **how do I get the event to trigger after the bean retrived the value, or how do I call the javascript function from the bean directly ?**

here is a sample of the code I use

```
<af:resource type="javascript">
     function pushValue(evt){
          // push values to parent page
          window.external.main.setFieldValue("fieldName", evt.getSource().getValue());
     }
     function callServerAPI(){
         // call the serverListener
         AdfCustomEvent.queue(it2, "callAPI", {somevalues}, true);
     }
</af:resource>
<af:inputText label="My hidden field" 
              id="it2" 
              binding="#{pageFlowScope.MyAppBean.hiddenField}"
              clientComponent="true">
              <af:clientListener method="pushValue" type="valueChange"/>
              <af:serverListener type="callAPI"
                                method="#{pageFlowScope.MyAppBean.callAPI}"/>
</af:inputText>
```

here is the sample for the bean

```
private RichInputText hiddenField;
public void callAPI(ClientEvent clientEvent) throws Exception {

    String fieldValue = clientEvent.getParameters().get("somevalues").toString();

    try {

        // call the API and get the value needed in the hidden field
        hiddenField.setValue(fetchValue(fieldValue));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // refresh field
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(hiddenField);        

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: There is a couple of article online on how to execute javascript from a bean. Did you try this : cedricleruth(dot)com/how-to-execute-client-javascript-in-an-adf-java-bean-action/ ?

Comment: Hi yes that is what I did, I learned that change push from the bean can't trigger client Listener event. the field is reloaded by the page not updated hence the reason why the event doesn't work. I re-writted my javascript function and I now call it from the bean in about the same way the link you gave me explain it. if you post your comment as an anwser, I can select it has the answer. otherwise I will post the answer myself for future reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-execute-client-javascript-in-an-adf-java-bean-action/ answer your question : ***"how do I call the javascript function from the bean directly ?"*** as follow :

```
/*** In YOURJSF.jsf button, or other component that need to execute a javascript on action, add : ****/
<af:commandButton text="ClickMe" id="cb1" actionListener="#{YOURSCOPE.YOURJAVABEAN.clickToExecuteJavascriptAction}"/>

 /*** In YOURJAVABEAN.java class add : ***/
 public void clickToExecuteJavascriptAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
  this.executeClientJavascript("console.log('You just clicked : " + actionEvent.getSource() + " ')");
  //Note: if you use a java string value in this function you should escape it to avoid breaking the javascript.
  //Like this : stringValue.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]", " ")
 }

//You should put this function in a util java class if you want to use it in multiple bean
public static void executeClientJavascript(String script) {
 FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 ExtendedRenderKitService service = Service.getRenderKitService(facesContext, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
 service.addScript(facesContext, script);
}
```